# Disable Splash/Welcome screen when in screensaver mode

Tags: unity, lock-screen, screensaver

My question is how to disable the splash (welcome) screen once in screen saver mode?

I have disabled the lock screen in settings, and Ubuntu does not require my password any longer when in screensaving mode. However, when the screens are off, and I move my mouse, there appears the splash (or welcome) screen, and I have to move it up in order to continue my session.

Is there a way to disable this option? To make Ubuntu not cover my desktop with this screen while going into sreen saving mode?

Thank you.

Comment: you can just press Escape Key instead of moving up the screen.

Comment: @DominikCornice, thank you for your answer. I was wondering if there is a way to totally disable this feature.